# If $\|\cdot\|_{1}\le\|\cdot\|_{2}$ then $\|\cdot\|_{2}\le M\|\cdot\|_{1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_{1})$ and $(X,\|\cdot\|_{2})$ be complete normed vector spaces and $\|x\|_{1}\le\|x\|_{2}$ $\forall x\in X$. I want to prove that $\exists M>0$ such that $\|x\|_{2}\le M\|x\|_{1}$.

We know that any Cauchy sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset X$ converges. And of course, $\frac{1}{M}\|x\|_{1}\le\|x\|_{1}\le M\|x\|_{1}$.

Does anyone have any hints on how I can proceed? I assume that I have to use this completeness property somehow.

Comment: since for a norm $||c x|| = |c| \, ||x||$ the norm $||.||_1$ is fully determined by its value on $||x||_2 = 1$ and conversely, so what you have to prove is $\max_{||x||_2 = 1} ||x||_1 = M < \infty$ (for any sequence $x_n \to x$ for $||.||_2$ then $x_n \to x$ for $||.||_1$)

Comment: @reuns Could you please elaborate on your idea of proof given in the comment or post it as an answer? I am looking for a proof of OP's question which does $\textit{not}$ use the open mapping theorem, but every answer in similar questions here does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity mapping $I : (X,\|\cdot\|_2) \to (X,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a bijection and by assumption is continuous. Since the spaces are complete you can appeal to the open mapping theorem. The inverse is also continuous.

Comment: So your argument proves that $\|\cdot\|_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_{2}$ are in fact equivalent, thus $\|x\|_{1}=\|x\|_{2}$ and therefore for any $M>0$ we have $\|x\|_{2}\le M\|x\|_{1}$?

Comment: Equivalent does not mean equal. Your last inequality holds for *some* $M > 0$, not all.